# ClassList not Toggling in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with my small accordion section. I'm doing the project with NextJS, and using functional components.

So I have this section where I added an onClick event to the div symbol (plus sign) :

```
<article className="about__accordion">
  <div className="about__accordion--title">
    <div className="about__accordion--symbolPlus" onClick={(e)=> toggleClass(e)}
      ></div>
    <h4>who we are</h4>
  </div>
  <div className="about__accordion--description">
    <p className="about__accordion--content">
      We’re a team of dedicated multidisciplinary young people with
      knowledge and ambition to execute & deliver high quality digital
      products. The bigger the challenge, the better. We push the
      boundaries.
    </p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Just above I added the function :

```
export default function About() {
    
  const toggleClass = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let currentElement = event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;

    let allAccordions = document.querySelectorAll(".about__accordion");
    allAccordions.forEach((event) => {
      let plusSymbol = currentElement.querySelector(
        ".about__accordion--symbolPlus"
      );
      let content = currentElement.querySelector(
        ".about__accordion--description"
      );

      plusSymbol.classList.toggle("active");
      content.classList.toggle("active");

    });
  };

  return (...........)
```

And I don't understand why toggle doesn't work, but add works fine.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you can toggle or change class names by using state variables.

You may not need all these querySelector and document controls.

Here is an example

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setActive(!isActive)}>
        Click this button to toggle class
      </button>
      <p className={`normal_text ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example link

[https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-grass-px7xb?file=/src/App.js:0-427](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-framework-ghj6x?file=/src/App.js)

use this method in your code to switch the class

Based on your question

1. https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-haze-mzo94?file=/src/App.js.
   In this method, only one active component will be there, (you can create the contents inside loop in one another component)
2. https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-framework-ghj6x?file=/src/App.js.
   Other than accordion if you need to open more than one section same time then use this method. this is added for the simplest understanding of class and state (Another method of implementation on same problem)

   In this method created a small component for the accordion .

   In this method, you can open more than one section same time.

note: No code duplicated in both methods,

Comment: At the beginning I started like this, but the issue is I have different div's with the same name classes for the accordion. So if one gets isActive, all the others gets active. I tried with for example isActive1, isActive2 for the second div, isActive for the third and so on, but I don't think its good, or I don't know how to do,  or maybe I'm wrong ...

Comment: NO don't use it 'Active!, Active2' ...., just active is engough create a state and store the accordion index id in that state. so if index in state is same with the current index add your class. another method is try to create a small component for each openable accordion (react suggest small components) and keep the state inside your small component. loop small component as much accordion you needed. if you need a working example create a code sandbox based on your sample code. i will update it with a best method

Comment: Thanks Sojin, here's a link to the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-dream-yq6i3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have updated the answer with two new links with your exact problem. try it

Comment: Added two solutions with two methods in the answer

Comment: Oh ok, I got the overall now. Thanks a lot. I'm going to look at it now more in steps by steps. Thanks Sojin

Comment: Ok done for the upvote and mark ;)